# Cannot insert data into mongo collection after cleaning it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a little trouble: I'm just trying to insert the list of raw records into mongodb collection right after I cleaned it. But I don't receive any feedback from `insert` method. This is my code:

```
model.collection.remove((removeError, removeResult) => {
  console.log('remove cb');
  model.collection.insert(seeds, (insertError, insertedRecords) => {
    console.log('insert cb');
  });
});
```

Actually I wanted to do this by using the mongoose API(model is the mongoose model) but on my way of exploring this problem I figured out that the native driver don't execute this as well.

That's what I have trying to use mongoose wrappers:

```
model.remove({}, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('remove error');
    } else {
        console.log('remove success');
        model.insertMany(seeds, (insertError, insertedRecords) => {
            if (insertError) {
                console.log('insert error');
            } else {
                console.log('insert success');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I run this script I see 'remove success' and that's all. And if I comment out the removing process then 'insert success' is displayed

My mongoose model is really simple:

```
const schema = new Schema({
   name: {type: String, unique: true, index: true},
});
```

`seeds` variable:

```
export default [
{name: 'USA'},
{name: 'Germany'},
{name: 'France'}, ...
```

Please explain me where am I wrong or what I don't understand

**UPD**

I have tried this using the `MongoClient` and it works!

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    const collection = db.collection('countries');
    collection.deleteMany({}, (err, r) => {
        console.log('delete', err);
        collection.insertMany(seeds, (err, r) => {
            console.log('insert', err);
            db.close();
            Country.find({}, function (err, res) {
                console.log(res);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

So problem is in the mongoose. Though actually I thought `{ModelName}.collection` is the native driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear up your confusion, this line `model.collection.remove((removeError, removeResult)` is wrong.

The syntax for remove is this, `db.collection.remove(
   <query>,
   <justOne>
)`

there is no query , but here `model.remove({}, (err, docs) => {` you do have query(`{}`) which means delete all.

examine this statement `db.mycol.remove({'title':'MongoDB Overview'})` which is a query to find and delete any document with a title of MongoDB Overview.

Does any of this makes sense?

Comment: As I understand `remove` method drops records from collection, not the collection itself

Comment: my fail, problem was in fact that I did disconnection non-asynchronously